# Tracing fIle path and line number

Tags: python, python-2.7, trace, filepath

I'm using python's `trace` module to trace some code. When I trace code this way, I can get one of the following two results:

**Call**:

```
tracer = trace.Trace(count=False, trace=True, ignoredirs=[sys.prefix, sys.exec_prefix])
r = tracer.run('run()')
tracer.results().write_results(show_missing=True)
```

**Result**:

```
<filename>(<line number>): <line of code>
```

**Call** [[citation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14496861/198633)]:

```
tracer = trace.Trace(count=False, trace=True, ignoredirs=[sys.prefix, sys.exec_prefix], countfuncs=True)
r = tracer.run('run()')
tracer.results().write_results(show_missing=True)
```

**Result**:

```
filename:<filepath>, modulename:<module name>, funcname: <function name>
```

What I really need is a trace that gives me this:

```
<filepath> <line number>
```

It would seem that I could use the above information and interleave them to get what I need, but such an attempt would fail in the following use case:

- `sys.path` contains directory `A` and directory `B`.
- There are two files `A/foo.py` and `B/foo.py`
- Both `A/foo.py` and `B/foo.py` contain the function `bar`, defined on lines 100 - 120
- There are some minor differences between `A/foo.py` and `B/foo.py`

In this scenario, using such interleaving to correctly identifying which `bar` is called is impossible (please correct me if I'm wrong) without statically analyzing the code within each `bar`, which itself is very difficult for non-trivial functions.

So, how can I get the correct trace output that I need?

Comment: Did you ever solve this one? I've got the same question.

Comment: Unfortunately, I ended up not having this problem. I think @aquavitae's solution might work though. Let me know if that solved it for you, so that I can accept that answer

Comment: I found a solution which is more or less the same as @aquavitae's solution: hack the trace module. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20947780/finding-full-pathname-in-a-python-trace?lq=1

Answer (score 1):

With a little monkey-patching, this is actually quite easy.  Digging around in the source code of the `trace` module it seems that callbacks are used to report on each execution step.  The basic functionality of `Trace.run`, greatly simplified, is:

```
sys.settrace(globaltrace)   # Set the trace callback function
exec function               # Execute the function, invoking the callback as necessary
sys.settrace(None)          # Reset the trace
```

`globaltrace` is defined in `Trace.__init__` depending on the arguments passed.  Specifically, with the arguments in your first example, `Trace.globaltrace_lt` is used as the global callback, which calls `Trace.localtrace_trace` for each line of execution.  Changing it is simply a case of modifying `Trace.localtrace`, so to get the result you want:

```
import trace
import sys
import time
import linecache

class Trace(trace.Trace):
    def localtrace_trace(self, frame, why, arg):
        if why == "line":
            # record the file name and line number of every trace
            filename = frame.f_code.co_filename
            lineno = frame.f_lineno

            if self.start_time:
                print '%.2f' % (time.time() - self.start_time),
            print "%s (%d): %s" % (filename, lineno,
                                  linecache.getline(filename, lineno)),
        return self.localtrace


tracer = Trace(count=False, trace=True, ignoredirs=[sys.prefix, sys.exec_prefix])
r = tracer.run('run()')
```

There is a difference between the two examples you give; if the first the output is printed during the `Trace.run` call, in the second it is printed during `write_results`.  The code I've given above follows the pattern of the former, so `tracer.results().write_results()` is not necessary.  However, if you want to manipulate this output instead it can be achieved by patching the `trace.CoverageResults.write_results` method in a similar manner.