# Finding full pathname in a Python trace

Tags: python, trace

When turning on Python trace, the filename is provided, along with the module and sourcecode.

Is it possible to show the file path as well as the filename?

I am using:

```
-m trace -t
```

In the example below there are two different **account_bank_statement.py** files in different directories.

```
17  --- modulename: account_bank_statement, funcname: button_create_invoice
18 account_bank_statement.py(329):         if context is None:
19 account_bank_statement.py(333):         currency =  self.read(cr, uid, ids, ['currency'])[0]['currency']
20  --- modulename: account_bank_statement, funcname: _currency
21 account_bank_statement.py(107):         res = {}
22 account_bank_statement.py(108):         res_currency_obj = self.pool.get('res.currency')
```

This is a duplicate of this (unanswered) question: [Tracing fIle path and line number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14638041/tracing-file-path-and-line-number#comment31443029_14638041)

An answer that would involve hacking the trace module would work for me.

**EDIT**

A solution, based on Alfe's answer below. It **is** intrusive, but is does what I an looking for. I have left the modulename and also added the pathname. I am working with OpenERP and there is often the same modulename defined in multiple locations.

I have not posted this an answer as it is really a refinement of Alfe's solution, so if you like please up vote his answer.

(1) Copy trace.py to your local path
(2) Edit as below:

```
171 def modname(path):
172     """Return a plausible module name for the patch."""
173 
174     base = os.path.basename(path)
175     filename, ext = os.path.splitext(base)
176     return filename

593     def globaltrace_lt(self, frame, why, arg):
594         """Handler for call events.
595 
596         If the code block being entered is to be ignored, returns `None',
597         else returns self.localtrace.
598         """
599         if why == 'call':
600             code = frame.f_code
601             filename = frame.f_globals.get('__file__', None)
602             if filename:
603                 # XXX modname() doesn't work right for packages, so
604                 # the ignore support won't work right for packages
605                 #modulename = fullmodname(filename)
606                 modfile, ext = os.path.splitext(filename)
607                 modulename = fullmodname(modfile)
608                 if modulename is not None:
609                     ignore_it = self.ignore.names(modfile, modulename)
610                     if not ignore_it:
611                         if self.trace:
612                             print (" --- modulename: %s, funcname: %s, filename: %s"
613                                    % (modulename, code.co_name, filename))
614                         return self.localtrace
615             else:
616                 return None
```

**Sample Output**

Note there are 2 different module names, contained in different directories, with the same filenames. This modified *trace.py** handles this.

```
2  --- modulename: register_accounting, funcname: button_create_invoice, filename: /home/sean/unifield/utp729/unifield-wm/register_accounting/account_bank_statement.pyc
3 account_bank_statement.py(329):         if context is None:
4 account_bank_statement.py(333):         currency =  self.read(cr, uid, ids, ['currency'])[0]['currency']
5  --- modulename: account, funcname: _currency, filename: /home/sean/unifield/utp729/unifield-addons/account/account_bank_statement.pyc
6 account_bank_statement.py(107):         res = {}
7 account_bank_statement.py(108):         res_currency_obj = self.pool.get('res.currency')
```

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14492837/pythons-trace-module-and-filepaths

Comment: I have answered the duplicate post, hopefully it will work for you too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If patching of `trace.py` is allowed, this task is easy.

Copy `trace.py` (from `/usr/lib/python2.7/` in my case) to a local directory (e. g. the current one), then patch the function `modname(path)` in that local copy.  That function strips the directories off the module paths, so the package information is lost.  The original contains the line

```
filename, ext = os.path.splitext(base)
```

which can be changed to

```
filename, ext = os.path.splitext(path)
```

in order to *not* strip the directory.

The output of a call like `./trace.py --trace t.py` then looks like this:

```
 --- modulename: t, funcname: <module>
t.py(3): import mypackage.mymodule
 --- modulename: mypackage/__init__, funcname: <module>
__init__.py(1):   --- modulename: mypackage/mymodule, funcname: <module>
mymodule.py(1): print 42
42
t.py(5): print 5
5
 --- modulename: ./trace, funcname: _unsettrace
trace.py(80):         sys.settrace(None)
```

I'm tracing a test script called `t.py` which imports a module `mymodule.py` which is in a package `mypackage` (so the filename is `./mypackage/mymodule.py`).  That module only prints 42, the test script itself prints 5.

Does this solve your issue?

EDIT:

Upon second view, I propose a different patch.

In function `globaltrace_lt()` the modulename is derived by calling `modname()`; patch this to call `fullmodname()`:

```
            modulename = fullmodname(filename)
```

I think this might be a less intrusive patch.

Comment: Hi Alfe, Thanks for your answer. It does solve the issue thank you. It does introduce a different issue: the --ignore-module must now include the full path.

Comment: Well, yeah, probably that's a logical consequence and desirable that way?

Comment: But on further inspection of the code I have a different suggestion.  See my EDIT in the answer above.

Comment: Thanks for your help Alfe. I have solved the issue which is a real problem on OpenERP where the inheritance model is non-standard.